# Submit form using Ajax and Swiftmailer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using ajax to submit a form using swiftmailer. I'm getting an error when I try to submit the form.  I think it has something to do with the "data" setting in the ajax call. I can get the swiftmailer mailing script to work fine when submitting a form not using ajax. You can see my work here, http://wickbuildings.com/form. I'm stuck and any help would be appreciated!

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button#send_btn").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/assets/js/mailers/become-a-builder.php",
            data: $('form[name=BecomeBuilderForm]').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                $("#thanks").html(msg) //hide button and show thank you
                $("#form-content").modal('hide'); //hide modal
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and my swiftmailer mailing script:

```
<?php

//grab named inputs from html then post to #thanks
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $email_dsm = strip_tags($_POST['email_dsm']);
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $business_name = strip_tags($_POST['business_name']);
    $address = strip_tags($_POST['address']);
    $city = strip_tags($_POST['city']);
    $state = strip_tags($_POST['state']);
    $zip = strip_tags($_POST['zip']);
    $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $comments = strip_tags($_POST['comments']);

    // create message that fills #thanks container
    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" >Thank you for your inquiry. " . $email_dsm . " will be following up with you shortly.</div>";

    // Create message of email to recipient
    $body = "the contents of the email here";

    require_once '../plugins/swiftmailer/swift_required.php';

    // Create the mail transport configuration
    $transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');

    // Create the message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
    $message->setTo(array(
        'user@somedomain.com'
    ));
    $message->setSubject('my email subject here');
    $message->setBody($body, 'text/html');
    $message->setFrom($Email);

    // Send the email
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $mailer->send($message);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forms don't need names. give it an ID.

```
<form id="BecomeBuilderForm">
```

then use:

```
$('#BecomeBuilderForm').serialize()
```

or if you really want to use the name add double quotes around BecomeBuilderForm

```
$('form[name="BecomeBuilderForm"]').serialize()
```

if you really get stuck make sure your form is serializing using console.log()

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button#send_btn").click(function(){
        console.log($('form[name="BecomeBuilderForm"]').serialize());
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried what you advised and it looks like the data is serializing. Via the console for my working example (http://wickbuildings.com/form), I'm getting a 500 error for the php script, but I can't understand how that is happening.  Thoughts?

Comment: 500 is a server error. check your apache or nginx logs